Data Upload Issue with Chinese Character Column Names in BigQuery
One issue I encountered while uploading data to a BigQuery table is that the column names are in Chinese characters. the data in these columns appears as null. How can this issue be resolved?
import pandas as pd
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery


data = {
    '学生姓名': ['张三', '李四', '王五'],
    '年龄': [20, 22, 21],
    '成绩': [85, 90, 88]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, 'your_dataset.your_table', project_id='your_project_id',
                   if_exists='replace', credentials=credentials, table_schema=schema)

bigquery table data
enter image description here
